# How to keep the attributes from dropdowns to next few pages using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dropdown

i have this codes from a dropdown page.(not all)

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            Sila pilih kategori peperiksaan
        </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">

                        <form name="selection" role="form" method="post" action="index.php?pages=peperiksaan2" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">


                        <div class="form-group">

                             <?php 


                            $sql = "SELECT tahun_nama FROM tahun";

                            $result = $con->query($sql);
                            ?>
                            <label for="tahun_nama">TAHUN</label>  
                            <select class="form-control" id="tahun_nama" name="tahun_id">
                                <option value=""<?php if(!isset($_POST['tahun_nama']) || (isset($_POST['tahun_nama']) && empty($_POST['tahun_nama']))) { ?>selected<?php } ?>>Sila pilih tahun</option>
                                <?php 
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

                                     echo '<option value="'.$row['tahun_nama'].'"'. ((isset($_SESSION['tahun_nama']) && !empty($_SESSION['tahun_nama']) && ($_SESSION['tahun_nama'] == $row['tahun_nama'])) ? 'selected="selected"' : '') .'>'.$row['tahun_nama'].' </option>';

                                }
                                ?>
                            </select>                                      
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php 
                            $sql = "SELECT peperiksaan_nama FROM peperiksaan"; 

                            $result = $con->query($sql);
                            ?>
                            <label>PEPERIKSAAN</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="peperiksaan_nama" name="peperiksaan_id">
                                <option value=""<?php if(!isset($_POST['peperiksaan_nama']) || (isset($_POST['peperiksaan_nama']) && empty($_POST['peperiksaan_nama']))) { ?>selected<?php } ?>>Sila pilih peperiksaan</option>
                                <?php 
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['peperiksaan_nama']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_POST['peperiksaan_nama']) && $_POST['peperiksaan_nama'] == $row['peperiksaan_nama']) { ?>selected<?php } ?>><?php echo $row['peperiksaan_nama']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </select>  
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php 
                            $sql = "SELECT darjah_nama FROM darjah"; 

                            $result = $con->query($sql);
                            ?>
                            <label>DARJAH</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="darjah_nama" name="darjah_id">
                                <option value=""<?php if(!isset($_POST['darjah_nama']) || (isset($_POST['darjah_nama']) && empty($_POST['darjah_nama']))) { ?>selected<?php } ?>>Sila pilih darjah</option>
                                <?php 
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $row['darjah_nama']; ?>" <?php if(isset($_SESSION['darjah_nama']) && $_SESSION['darjah_nama'] == $row['darjah_nama']) { ?>selected<?php } ?>><?php echo $row['darjah_nama']; ?></option>
                                <?php } ?>

                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <?php 


                            $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM kelas");
                            ?>
                            <label>KELAS</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="kelas_nama" name="kelas_id">
                                <option value=""<?php if(!isset($_POST['kelas_nama']) || (isset($_POST['kelas_nama']) && empty($_POST['kelas_nama']))) { ?>selected<?php } ?>>Sila pilih kelas</option>
                                <?php 
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                                        echo " <option value=" . $row['kelas_nama'] . ">" . $row['kelas_nama'] ."</option>"; } ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                     <!--   <button style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" type="submit" name="select" class="btn btn-primary" href="pptt415.php">PAPAR</button-->

                             <!--center><a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?pages=newpptt415" role="button">PAPAR</a></center-->

                            <center><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">PAPAR</button></center>

                          <!--a class="btn btn-primary" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" href="index.php?pages=edit_guru&guru_nama=?php echo $guru_nama ?>" role="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a-->



                        </form>   
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

and this the page after selecting the options from dropdown where user needs to import file based on the option selected.. (a few codes below)

```
 <center><h4 class="page-header">PEPERIKSAAN : <?php

        $peperiksaan_nama=$_POST["peperiksaan_id"];
        echo $peperiksaan_nama ?> <br>
        MATAPELAJARAN : Matematik <br>
        KELAS : <?php 
        $kelas_nama=$_POST['kelas_id'];
        $darjah_nama=$_POST['darjah_id'];
            echo $darjah_nama; ?> <?php
            echo $kelas_nama; ?> <br> 
        TAHUN : <?php  $tahun_nama=$_POST['tahun_id']; echo $tahun_nama?>
    </h4></center> 

<center>    <form id="import" name="import" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" /><br />
    <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" value="Import"/> <br><br>
</form>  </center>

<?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $handle = fopen($file, "r");
    $c = 0;
    while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false)
    {

        $murid_ic = $filesop[0];
        $murid_nama = $filesop[1];
        $murid_markah = $filesop[2];
        $murid_gred = $filesop[3];
        $tahun_id = $filesop[4];
        $peperiksaan_id = $filesop[5];
        $kelas_id = $filesop[6];
        $darjah_id = $filesop[7];    


        $query = query("INSERT INTO murid (murid_ic,murid_nama, murid_markah, murid_gred, tahun_id, peperiksaan_id, kelas_id, darjah_id) 

        VALUES ('$murid_ic','$murid_nama','$murid_markah','$murid_gred','$tahun_id','$peperiksaan_id','$kelas_id','$darjah_id')");

        $c = $c + 1;
    }

        if($query){

            redirect("index.php?pages=peperiksaan2&tahun_id=$tahun_id&peperiksaan_id=$peperiksaan_id&darjah_id=$darjah_id&kelas_id=$kelas_id");
                echo "You database has imported successfully. You have inserted ". $c ." recoreds";
        }else{
            echo "Sorry! There is some problem.";
        }

}
?>


    <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BIL</th>
                    <th>NAMA</th>
                    <th>NO IC</th>
                    <th><center>MARKAH</center></th>
                    <th><center>GRED</center></th>
                </tr>   
              </thead>

        <?php            

            $bil = 0;

            $SQLSELECT = "SELECT murid.*, peperiksaan.*, tahun.*, darjah.*, kelas.* FROM murid, peperiksaan, tahun, darjah, kelas WHERE murid.peperiksaan_id = peperiksaan.peperiksaan_id AND murid.tahun_id = tahun.tahun_id AND murid.darjah_id = darjah.darjah_id AND murid.kelas_id = kelas.kelas_id" ;

            $result_set =  mysqli_query($con, $SQLSELECT);

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result_set))
            {
                $bil++;
            ?>

                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo $bil; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['murid_nama']; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $row['murid_ic']; ?></td>
                    <td><center><?php echo $row['murid_markah']; ?></center></td>
                    <td><center><?php echo $row['murid_gred']; ?></center></td>     

                </tr>


            <?php
            }
        ?>
```

it happen to be just fine.. but after importing a file.. the attributes wont read the values from options anymore. why is that happen? the import button leads to the same page anyway.

Answer (score 0):

store your values in cookie and use when you want